# Как сменить цвет состояний AppCompatRadioButton

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, view

Есть вот такой RadioButton:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
                android:id="@+id/leftRadioButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/radio_group_stroke_color"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:duplicateParentState="true" />
```

Мне нужно сменить цвет самого `RadioButton`. Знаю, что это можно сделать вот так:

```
android:buttonTint="@color/common_blue"
```

Но так меняется полностью его цвет, а мне нужно чтоб он менялся в определенном состоянии только. Пробовал вот такой вариант:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/background_engaging" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/transparent" android:state_checked="false" />
</selector>
```

Но в этом случае меняется его фон. А мне нужно именно сама иконка [image: иконка]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Интересный вопрос :) Пришлось поковыряться, но мне кажется я нашел то что вам нужно. Есть такая штука [ColorStateList](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource). Я не очень понял где находится ваш файлик с селекторами, поэтому расскажу как я понял - создаем папку `res/color/selector.xml` и дальше пишем туда ваш код (дальше будет мой код, так как цветов ваших у меня нету):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/colorAccent" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/black" android:state_checked="false" />
</selector>
```

и дальше применяем его в xml:

```
android:buttonTint="@color/selector"
```

Кружок будет менять цвет при выборе (тут я не очень понял получилось у вас такое или нет). Есть второй вариант - программно. При этои buttonTint в xml лучше не ставить. Делаем переменную:

```
val colorStateList = ColorStateList(arrayOf(intArrayOf(-android.R.attr.state_checked), intArrayOf(android.R.attr.state_checked)), intArrayOf(
                Color.RED //state_unchecked
                , Color.BLUE //state_checked
))
```

берем вашу кнопку и сеттим ей этот тинтлист:

```
radio.backgroundTintList = colorStateList
```

Вот нашел подобные вопросы, может помогут: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17120199/change-circle-color-of-radio-button), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17120199/change-circle-color-of-radio-button). [Документация](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#setButtonTintList(android.content.res.ColorStateList)).

P.S. С меня +1 за интересный вопрос :D