# Как сделать переливающуюся рамку вокруг ConstraintLayout?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, color, градиент

На экране имеется 6 `ConstraintLayout`, внутри каждого какое-то содержимое в виде одного `ImageView`, но не суть. Я могу запросто сделать рамку вокруг одного цвета статичного с помощью:

```
<shape android:shape="rectangle"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="@dimen/main_border_radius" />
    <stroke
        android:color="@color/colorAccent"
        android:width="1dp" />
</shape>
```

Я также могу сделать цвет градиента:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:type="linear"
        android:angle="0"
        android:startColor="#f6ee19"
        android:endColor="#115ede" />
</shape>
```

Но проблема в том,что оба этих файла находятся в `Drawable`, то есть я не могу задать цвет рамки = цвету градиента.

1. Есть ли возможность задать цвет градиента в colors или другим способом что бы задать цвет рамки градиентный.
2. Если можно только динамически,то как и можно ли сделать переливания этой рамки? Если код,то желательно Kotlin.

Спасибо

Comment: Ну я ща могу ошибаться, но по-моему вы можете здавать в drawable ресурсе цвет из другого drawable. Только использовать надо selector

Comment: <color name="gradient">@drawable/gradient_color</color> так не работает.А color из drawable рамки требует только color ресурс...

Comment: https://medium.com/over-engineering/manipulating-images-and-drawables-with-androids-colorfilter-25bf061843e7 Посмотрите, может быть поможет вам. Но тут правда все в коде. А я вот недавно делал цвет и в ресурсы прокидывал цвет из drawable https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1141318/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%86%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-appcompatradiobutton вот посмотрите

Comment: так у вас color уже задан в selector. То есть у вас android:color="@color/background_engaging". А надо как-то сделать android:color="@drawable/gradient" Потому что градиент как сам цвет лежит в drawable